# Is it possible to rename the file before uploading to server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Hello i am making mean application in which i have to upload picture.I want when uploading these picture before going to server I want rename this picture so that when it  goes to server than the filename is new file name.
For example i upload `img1.png` so my controller change the name image to`asd232.png` and new file name should go to server.

Comment: how are you uploading the images from angular ? can show some code of angular

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Provided that you have access to `FormData` being sent to server you could change file name when appending a file using the third parameter of `append` method. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

> ```
> formData.append('userpic', myFileInput.files[0], 'chris.jpg');
> ```

Comment: @Andrew Not working how? Any errors? Show your code otherwise it is impossible to help.

Comment: Hey Buddy Thanks a lot ... you save my time and lots of KB... :)